# Happy Birthday, let's have some cake!

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

It's my friend's birthday soon and since he is a programmer and ASCII art lover, I thought I'd make him some ASCII cake!

Sadly, I keep forgetting his current age, so I would like to have a program for my ASCII oven, that bakes a cake with a specified number of candles, so I don't have to do it myself again if I am wrong with his age.

ASCII ovens only have limited memory and storage capacity, so it should use the *fewest bytes possible*.

---

### Your Task:

Write a program that outputs a birthday cake to the console, with as many candles as the input specifies.

Cake requirements are:

- It has to have a border, built up of horizontal `-` and vertical `|` lines, and vertices `+`.
- Atleast 5 characters wide (including cake border `|`)
- Atleast 5 characters high (including cake border `-`)
- There has to be a whitespace character  between the cake border and the first candle-base (not the flame), on each side, except if there is a flame in that space. A flame or candle-base should not be able to overlap the cake borders.
- The maximum width of the cake is 9 characters, so there is a maximum of 5 candles per row.
- Since we don't want our cake to be 2-dimensional, it has to be an extra 2 rows high, to give it some volume. Add another border at the bottom and connect the vertices with the ones above them, again using the ASCII characters from above (`-`, `|` and `+`).

Candle requirements are:

- Consists of the base `|` and the flame `*`, with the flame stacked on top of the base.
- Candles may not be directly adjacent to eachother, except diagonally.
- Candles are placed left-to-right, then top-to-bottom, with 5 in one line at maximum.
  (Note: If there were 5 candles in the previous row, the next row can't possibly have 5 aswell, since then they would be adjacent.)

**Additional notes:**

- The cake width depends on the number of candles in the *first* row, but it has to be a minimum of 5 characters and a maximum of 9 characters wide.
- The candles are filled starting in the top-most row, going left to right. Once one row if full the next one should start in the row below the first one.

### Input:

You may accept a number in (reasonable) format you like.

For this challenge you may assume that the number is between 0 and 2<sup>31</sup> (not including 0), even though I don't acknowledge someone who is this old.

### Output:

You can either return a string or directly write the resulting cake into the output console.

### Rules:

- Standard [loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes, in any language, wins.

---

### Examples:

Input: `8`

```
+-----------+
| * * * * * |
| |*|*|*| | |
|  | | |    |
|           |
+-----------+
|           |
+-----------+
```

Input: `2`

```
+-----+
| * * |
| | | |
|     |
+-----+
|     |
+-----+
```

Input: `12`

```
+-----------+
| * * * * * |
| |*|*|*|*| |
| *|*|*| |  |
| | | |     |
|           |
+-----------+
|           |
+-----------+
```

---

Good luck!

Comment: Can there be multiple valid solutions for an input?

Comment: @officialaimm Since there are specifications for candle-ordering and cake-sizing it should not be possible.

Comment: Useless fact: If you celebrate your birthday every second instead of every year, then 2^31 ~= 68 year-old. But that makes a lot of cakes every day and might become tedious after some time.

Comment: @Arnauld Unless you're a sharer you better own a lot of land to store all those cakes.

Comment: @Arnauld But then 99% of the time it's not your birthday :( ... except if you are celebrating the general fact that you were born.

Comment: @IanH. Let's say that you're celebrating your inception timestamp, then. :-)

Comment: @TheLethalCoder We can totally store these cakes into an array, no problem.

Answer (score 10):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>76</s> <s>71</s> <s>70 66</s> 46 bytes

```
ＮθＦ=+Ｂ⁺³⌊⟦χ⁺θθ⟧÷⁺℅ι⁺θθ⁹↘↘Ｆθ«↑|*¶¶¿‹⁶﹪⁺ιι⁹«Ｍ⁹←↓
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5Pa8IwGMbP7ad46enNFkE3GNjhRbwU1Imw0/RQ29S@kCZt2tTB9LNnNd1hB4/Pj@dfVqYm06l0LlG17ba2OgmDDXsPC20Ao8VzxGCpv3EnbYuvHDakqLIVfs2mHDxsODTsyBiHRHUr6ikXo/vD5KRSicT@OwcxZ0P/RvcC45W@qD2dy@4h8R8aBj9hsDOkOsD4s@YQXZ8O6qCiwRFQAbgWbYtvwzedW6nHceJA45SPB758ziFei@Je/Uf83F3ewptzsxc36d2klb8) Link is to verbose version of code. Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @ASCII_Only. Saved a massive 20 bytes by discovering a neat way of drawing the candles. Explanation:

```
ＮθＦ=+Ｂ⁺³⌊⟦χ⁺θθ⟧÷⁺℅ι⁺θθ⁹
```

Calculate the size both of the whole cake including extra volume and just the top of the cake so that they can be drawn. ((`=` = ASCII 61) = (`+` = ASCII 43) + 9 * 2 for the extra volume.)

```
↘↘Ｆθ«
```

Move the cursor to the first row of 5 candles. Loop through each candle.

```
↑|*¶¶
```

Print a candle and move right two characters for the next candle.

```
¿‹⁶﹪⁺ιι⁹«
```

However after the (zero-indexed) 4th, 8th, 13th, 17th, 22nd etc. candles (that are at the end of a row),

```
Ｍ⁹←↓
```

move the cursor to the first candle on the next row. This works on both odd and even rows!

Comment: Your solution puts an (unwanted) extra row for input number smaller than 6. :)

Comment: @IanH. Sorry, I thought that was the minimum height for some reason. Fixing that actually saved me 4 bytes!

Comment: Still displays wrong on TIO :/

Comment: @IanH. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU47CgJBDL2PpTdatrEQBGubaUYQC@20WrRYQdHCT2ZWB4TYxzvkAnOEMQkuDJm8vE9Sj6ppPanGpeS0y@lCUf5PYPdkp5UiRXYdBRkLxBsvF9y033nPNQeCnPYEZgEV9uBOgf1GnnkfSgWKeFJoKRIQ/gGtePx6NkBAMPlLSLBrpLcL1H/WtaDaFb5zd6SAV/Zb2VHK8Ac "Charcoal – Try It Online") gives me identical output to your example...

Comment: Alright, now it does :) great job on the solution!

Comment: @Neil remember you don't need the `Ａ` at the start :P (btw thanks for finding another golfer (not-so-)edge case)

Comment: `⁺θθ` can be `×²θ`...;)

Comment: @ASCII-only I can't believe I forgot that...

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer :/ same bytecount

Comment: @ASCII-only I just said that since Neil might've attempted to avoid the trailing `²` on `×θ²`...

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Actually I've got a tip on the Tips page about that...

Comment: @Neil I've already read that one.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 67 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
s9s€5Ẏa;⁶;⁶z⁶Z
ç”|ṙ-ż"ç”*$U⁸RḤ’¤¦Ẏ€j@€“| “|”Zj@€⁾--Z”+®¦€0,1©¦;ṫ¥-Y
```

A monadic link taking a number and returning a list of characters or a full program printing the output.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/YsvhR0xrTh7v6Eq0fNW4D4SogjuI6vPxRw9yahztn6h7dowTmaKmEPmrcEfRwx5JHDTMPLTm0DKgJqDfLAUg8aphTowAigOqiICKN@3R1o4Bc7UPrDi0DChjoGB5aeWiZ9cOdqw8t1Y38//@/kSEA)**

#### How?

```
s9s€5Ẏa;⁶;⁶z⁶Z - Link 1, make some candle parts & topping: number, age; character, part
s9             - split (implicit range(age)) into chunks of 9 (or remainder)
  s€5          - split each chunk of 9 into chunks of 5 (a 5 and a 4 or remainder)
     Ẏ         - tighten (to a list of lists of length 5, 4, 5, 4, ..., remainder)
      a        - logical and with the part character (either | or * here)
       ;⁶      - concatenate a space (we all still want topping when no candles)
         ;⁶    - ...and another (we also want some extra topping below the last row)
           z⁶  - transpose with filler space (fill the top with topping!)
             Z - transpose (put it back around the right way again chef)

ç”|ṙ-ż"ç”*$U⁸RḤ’¤¦Ẏ€j@€“| “|”Zj@€⁾--Z”+®¦€0,1©¦;ṫ¥-Y - Main link: number, age
ç”|                                                  - call last link (1) as a dyad with '|'
   ṙ-                                                - rotate left by -1
          $                                          - last two links as a monad:
       ç”*                                           -   call (1) as a dyad with '*'
      "                                              - zip with the dyadic operation:
     ż                                               -   zip (interleave each)
                 ¦                                   - sparse application:
           U                                         - ...of: upend (reverse each)
                ¤                                    - ...to indexes: nilad+links as a nilad:
            ⁸                                        -   chain's left argument, age
             R                                       -   range
              Ḥ                                      -   double (vectorises)
               ’                                     -   increment
                  Ẏ€                                 - tighten €ach (from '|*' or '*|' pairs)
                       “| “|”                        - literal ["| ", "|"]
                    j@€                              - join (swap arguments) for €ach (add a little extra topping to the left, and add piping to the sides)
                             Z                       - transpose
                                 ⁾--                 - literal "--"
                              j@€                    - join (swap arguments) for €ach (add piping to the top and bottom edges)
                                    Z                - transpose (time to invest in a potters wheel!)
                                              ¦      - sparse application:
                                          0,1        - ...to indexes: [0,1] (both ends)
                                             ©       -   (copy that to the register)
                                         €           - ...of: for each:
                                        ¦            -   sparse application:
                                     ”+              -   ...of: '+' character
                                       ®             -   ...to indexes: recall from register (both ends)
                                                  -  - literal -1
                                                 ¥   - last two links as a dyad
                                                ṫ    -   tail from index (gets last two rows)
                                               ;     -   concatenate (repeats them underneath)
                                                   Y - join with newlines
                                                     - as a full program: implicit print
```

Comment: Holy what +1 for beating Charcoal

Comment: @ASCII-only Sorry, I found a 4-byte saving...

Comment: @Neil well that's good too, Charcoal is supposed to be good at ASCII art (better than jelly) after all :P

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 94 bytes

```
/4½ c ÆYu ç +Um5-Yu)ÇV°<U?Q:SÃ¸+(1+Yu)ç
"| {Ug ç}|"
Vd"|+ -"
[W¡"| {X}|"ÃVVWVW]c ·y rQ+S"*|" y
```

[Try it online!](https://codepen.io/justinm53/full/NvKjZr?code=LzS9IGMgxll1IOcgK1VtNS1ZdSnHVrA8VT9ROlPDuCsoMStZdSnnCiJ8IHtVZyDnfXwiClZkInwrIC0iCltXoSJ8IHtYfXwiw1ZWV1ZXXWMgt3kgclErUyIqfCIgeQ==&inputs=OA==,Mg==,MTU=,MzU=)